# Prevent Struts 2 JSON plugin from escaping already formatted JSON

Tags: java, javascript, json, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

I have a JSON string like this:

```js
{"name": "Simple name", "description": "simple description"}
```

The Struts 2 JSON plugin returns an escaped string like this:

```
{\"name\": \"Simple name\", \"description\": \"simple description\"}
```

How do I configure the Struts 2 JSON plugin to prevent this escaping?

Comment: Struts 2 return you raw json. cast this json in StringBuilder  and now cast in string. it work as normal formated json.

Comment: Don't use the JSON plugin if you're creating your own JSON. The whole point of the JSON plugin is to expose the action properties as JSON (similar to how they're exposed to a JSP view). If you're doing that work yourself it's not required.